# Are there affordable palaces available as accommodation?

Tags: accommodation, history

I just came across [Bored of hotels? Stay in a palace](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/travel/world/bored-of-hotels-stay-in-a-palace/story-fni0e5l4-1226667990468)

> If 6-star hotels just aren't doing it for you anymore, we have the
>   answer.
>
> Palaces.
>
> Yep, that's right. You can live like a king in a palace, and let us
>   tell you, it's pretty awesome.

Unfortunately, the prices are a bit on the expensive side.

Are there more affordable (presumably former) palaces available as accommodation?

Affordable: ideally less than US$200 a night twin-share, or US$150 for a single. Failing that, less than US$200 per person. (The article talks about rooms at the palaces, rather than renting the entire palace out!)

Location: In the [Asia-Pacific region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia-Pacific): [East Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asia), [Southeast Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeast_Asia) and [Ocenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceania).

Related question: [Is there any way to spend a night in a European castle?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/is-there-any-way-to-spend-a-night-in-a-european-castle)

Comment: Presumably you have a country or region in mind? There are literally [HUNDREDS and HUNDREDS of palaces worldwide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_palaces).  I protest that this is too broad in its current form.

Comment: what means *affordable* for you?

Comment: If _affordable_ is defined, i will vote to reopen.

Comment: @MarkMayo how many are available as accommodation?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm no idea, had no intention of looking at all of them :) If it were, say, in Japan, then there'd be a handy list of 12 I would have researched.

Comment: @Dirty-flow now defined, including the single supplement.

Comment: @HaLaBi now defined.

Comment: Still way too broad, imho.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm +1 and voted to re-oprn

Comment: Casted the last reopend vote since affordable is now really well defined.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold because the geographical range is still too broad.

Answer (score 3):

It's at the high end of your price range (lowest price seems to be 160 EUR for a single room, 190 for a  double), but [Schlosshotel Kronberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlosshotel_Kronberg) is the closest I could find in Germany. It's a real historical palace (built in 1893 for a dowager Empress, still owned by a former royal family) and looks like it.

[image]