# Ireland castle hotel options

Tags: accommodation, hotels, ireland, architecture

We are going to Ireland for 2 weeks in early June for our honeymoon and would like to spend at least one night in a castle. So far in planning our itinerary we had decided to stay for about 3 nights in four places. The first will be Dublin since we're flying in there. After that, we haven't decided. I looked into Dromoland castle, but it's very expensive to stay 3 nights and it looks as if they might be booked for our dates anyway.

What are some other great castle hotels we could stay at in the southern half of the Republic of Ireland?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to spend a night in a European castle?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/is-there-any-way-to-spend-a-night-in-a-european-castle)

Comment: Just a heads up: there are many things in Ireland that are called a "castle", but could be more accuratly called a "stately home". If you want a castle castle (with turrets and big walls), be sure to check out the photos of the place first.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/is-there-any-way-to-spend-a-night-in-a-european-castle) that has an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3963/24596) with a link to a website to [book nights in a castle](http://www.celticcastles.com/). It has an option to search by country and in Ireland alone there is over a dozen options!

Comment: I had seen this question and answer, but was really hoping there would be more information since the number of castle hotels on that website is very limited.

Comment: @pnuts I edited the answer, now it has a direct link to Mark Mayo's answer. Thanks!

Comment: @LatentParent No one of the 17 castles available in the site does fit your needs? There is, for instance, Clontarf Castle, in the subrubs of Dublin, with prices starting below 100 Euros, or Ballyseede Castle in soutwest Ireland with prices starting on half the value of Dromoland Castle (which you mentioned in your question). Perhaps you may want to add details to your question on specific needs you might have on your search for a castle.